# Unable to run access EC2 server via cron job

Tags: python, ftp, cron, paramiko

I am trying to get the directory structure for a FTP user remotely. I am doing this from a python script using [spur][1] module. I am calling this script using a cron job. But I am getting the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/voylla-staging/releases/20140717193920/voylla_scripts/snapdeal/GetOrders/getOrders.py", line 54, in <module>
    feeds = getFeeds()
  File "/mnt/voylla-staging/releases/20140717193920/voylla_scripts/snapdeal/GetOrders/getOrders.py", line 26, in getFeeds
    result = shell.run(["ls", FEED_LOCATION])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spur/ssh.py", line 73, in run
    return self.spawn(*args, **kwargs).wait_for_result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spur/ssh.py", line 83, in spawn
    channel = self._get_ssh_transport().open_session()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/spur/ssh.py", line 190, in _get_ssh_transport
    raise self._connection_error(error)
spur.ssh.ConnectionError: Error creating SSH connection
Original error: Authentication failed.
```

If I run the scipt manually without using the cron, its runs perfectly fin!
Please can someone help.

Thanks

Relevant Code:

```
FTP_SERVER = "abc.example.com"
FTP_USER = "root"
FEED_LOCATION = "/home/xyz/abc"
PROCESSED_FEED_LOCATION = "/home/xyz/def"
PREFIX = "alpha"

def getFeeds():                                                                 ####returns the list of feeds in FEED_LOCATION
    shell = spur.SshShell(hostname=FTP_SERVER, username=FTP_USER)
    with shell:
        result = shell.run(["ls", FEED_LOCATION])
        feeds = result.output.decode().split("\n")
    return feeds

feeds = getFeeds()
```

Comment: I wonder if it's an issue with ssh keys. Is the cron job running as the same user as when you execute the script successfully? Can you execute a simple ssh command from cron, like `ssh root@abc.example.com ls`?

Comment: The command runs fine. and gives the expected output!

Comment: Oh and I am running the cron as the same user, root in both cases

Comment: Try to specify the `private_key_file` option with spur.

Comment: @kranteg: Worked by combining with [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/306798/trying-to-do-ssh-authentication-with-key-files-server-refused-our-key). If you could post as an answer that I can accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the path of your private key file with the `private_key_file` option. Here is the example from the [documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spur).

```
# Use a private key
spur.SshShell(
    hostname="localhost",
    username="bob",
    private_key_file="path/to/private.key"
)
```